# How can I check catalina.out logs from tomcat container?

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers, devops, catalina

I cant find any catalina.out file in tomcat container.

If I do docker logs , it shows container logs, but I want to see the logs generated by my application when it runs on tomcat.

Comment: Please consider to ask on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Could you add docker image url and also more details of your container?